# ¿Cómo no perder caracteres especiales al procesar archivos de texto en un bat?

Tags: windows, batch

Tengo este documento de texto (txt1.txt):

```
&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~.mp3  
¿¡áéíóú!.mp3
```

Al procesarlo con un comando FOR pierdo caracteres como "^" y "!".

En bat es el siguiente (tiene dos comandos FOR que a lo mejor se podrían resumir en uno solo, y el segundo tiene un ECHO al final que no sé si podría implementar mejor):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
CHCP 1252
SET TXTFILE1=txt1.txt
SET TXTFILE2=txt2.txt
(
    FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%I IN (%TXTFILE1%) DO (
        SET LINE=%%I
        ECHO !LINE:.mp3=!
    )
) > %TXTFILE2%
SET LINENUMBER=1
SET TXTFILE3=txt3.bat.txt
FOR /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%J IN (%TXTFILE2%) DO (
    ECHO SET TRACK!LINENUMBER!=%%J>> %TXTFILE3%
    SET /A LINENUMBER+=1
)
ECHO EXIT /B>> %TXTFILE3%
ENDLOCAL
PAUSE > NUL | SET /P =Presione una tecla para salir . . . & ECHO(
EXIT
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo ^&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~
```

añadiendo "^" delante de todo debería de arreglarse ya que este operador elimina la función de &(and) el cual daba error en la sintaxis.